# How trigger UseEffect Once with dependencies?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `useEffect()` Method, that runs once when the component is loaded.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async function fetchData() {
      const results = await stateIsoAPI();
      setStates(results);  // API results to other trigger other Use effect
    })();
  }, []);
```

But I need only when the user type info for first time.

If I add state dependency of input value it triggers every time that user type:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    (async function fetchData() {
      const results = await stateIsoAPI();
      setStates(results);  // API results to other trigger other Use effect
    })();
  }, [<inputValueState>]);
```

But it is not the desired behavior. How can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a fast-exit condition before `IIFE`

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if(!isFirstTime(<inputValueState>)) {
      return () => {}
   }

    (async function fetchData() {
      const results = await stateIsoAPI();
      setStates(results);  // API results to other trigger other Use effect
    })();
}, [<inputValueState>]);
```

Comment: Fancy and works like a charm, thank you I will select this answer.